# Laravel: Eloquent, many to many relationship, how do I eager load only the id of related model?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Eloquent to select a single row from a table called "businesses".  Any business can be associated with one or more "Industries".  I've set this up in the business model such that:

```
public function industries() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Industry');
}
```

In the controller I am eager loading the industries when I select the model:

```
$mdl = Business::find($business_id);
$mdl->load('industries');
return Response::json($mdl);
```

This returns something like this:

```
{"id":123,"name":"My Business","address":"123 Easy Street","industries":[{"id":1,"name":"Technology"},{"id":7,"name":"Research"}]}
```

This is almost what I need.  I'm looking to just have the response look like this instead:

```
{"id":123,"name":"My Business","address":"123 Easy Street","industries":[1,7]}
```

I know I could just do something like this:

```
$ind = array();
foreach($mdl->industries as $industry) $ind[] = $industry->id;
$mdl->industries = $ind;
```

I'd rather not do that though.  It's ugly and it makes my code look very non-laravel.

The reason I'd like to do it this way in the first place is because when I SAVE the business I am going to use something like this:

```
$mdl->industries()->sync(Input::get('industries'));
```

The SYNC method only accepts an array of IDs so I'd rather the JSON object going to and from the server have the same format.  I'd really rather not an array of objects when I load it and an array of ids when I save.  Is there a best practice for this sort of thing or an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
$mdl = Business::with('industries')->find($business_id)->toArray();
$mdl['industries'] = array_pluck($mdl['industries'], 'id');
return $mdl;
```

---

If you use this a lot, add the following method to your `Business` model:

```
public static function getWithIdustryIds ($business_id)
{
    $mdl = Business::with('industries')->find($business_id)->toArray();
    $mdl['industries'] = array_pluck($mdl['industries'], 'id');
    return $mdl;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the model so I don't need to repeat this code in every controller?

Comment: @BenjaminOman - Just add a static method to your model. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your model relationship should be

```
public function industries() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Industry::class);
}
```

Assuming that your pivot table has an industry_id column you can eager load only the industry_ids using

```
$mdl = Business::with(['industries' => function($query){
    $query->select('industry_id');
}])->get()
```